# How to hidden one word in HTML document with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need hidden all occurrences of a word in an HTML document using CSS. Is that possible?

not contain an identifier or class, the html is result of web scraper action

example

```
<tr class="">
    <th>EUROS BILLETE</th>
    <td>30.10</td>
    <td>31.99</td>
</tr>
```

In the sample code, I need hidden BILLET word, not's posible add any html tag, the code is result from web scraper action.

Comment: Provide your HTML code please

Comment: No. But you can do it with javascript.

Comment: After pasting some code, select it and click the Code Sample button (`{}`) or press the hotkey Ctrl+K.

Comment: Can you specify how you are scraping this data? How does html and css come into play in this question?

Answer (score 3):

No. In html/css you can hide elements, not text. You should wrap the word in an element such as a `span` and hide the element

```
<span class="text-to-hide">Whatever to text you want to hide</span>

span.text-to-hide
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr class="cell">
    <th class="hides">EUROS BILLETE</th>
    <td>30.10</td>
    <td>31.99</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jquery

```
   $(function() {


        // 
        //$('th:contains("EUROS BILLETE")').css('display', 'none');


        //or
        $('.hides').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().indexOf('BILLETE') != -1;
       }).remove();

        var th=$('<th>' + "EUROS" + '</th>');
        $('.cell').append(th);
    });
```

css

```
 <p class="youclass">paragraph</p>

   .youclass{
    display: none;
    }
```

and mostrate

```
.youclass{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: But you'd have to add spans all over the place…

Comment: sorry I did not understand you :)

Comment: You are selecting a class - so you need a class.

Comment: @bjb568 what's wrong with "adding spans all over the place"?

Comment: not matter. what is known is taught but not much :)

Comment: @bjb568 is it? I thought that's what html/css is all about...adding "spans and divs all over the place"

Comment: @Leo You add as few as possible to get the job done. No, adding thousands of container divs is not the point of HTML.

Comment: @bjb568 do you really know what you're talking about? Coz I don't, ok, back to the context...he wants to HIDE text, wrapping text within spans "gets the job done"...doesn't it?

Comment: It gets it done, but it bloats the markup and is annoying to put in. It's a perfectly valid answer, but not very practical.